# Why is my parameter always undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in a for loop and it's supposed to make all the items do the useItem function with their name as the parameter

```
if(invType[i] == "usable"){
    console.log(invName[i]);
    document.getElementById(i).onclick = function(){useItem(invName[i])};
}
```

and then this is the useItem function

```
function useItem(object){
    switch(object){
        case "sword":
            console.log("sword");
            break;
    }
    console.log("finished");
}
```

What is happening is that in the for loop `console.log(invName[i]);` is printing "sword" as it should, and it assigns the element the onclick function ok, but it isn't outputting what it should. It always thinks its undefined, so `case "sword":` never runs, but it does print "finished" fine. I just cant see what could be going wrong here.

Comment: `object` is a reserved word, so you should change that to something else (`obj`, for instance). That probably isn't causing your problem here though.

Comment: When you write `document.getElementById(i).onclick = function(){useItem(invName[i])};` the variable `i` won't stick to the value you put in the function. You need to say `document.getElementById(i).onclick = function(i) { return function(){useItem(invName[i])}; }(i);`

Comment: That solved it, why do I need the (i) at the very end though?